# Asp.net Treeview with check boxes

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkbox, treeview

Below is my treeview control in aspx page

```
 <asp:TreeView ID="TvCategories" runat="server" ShowCheckBoxes="All"    OnSelectedNodeChanged="TvCategories_SelectedNodeChanged">
</asp:TreeView>
```

I am binding it dynamically as below:

```
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    ds = BindCategories();
    dt = ds.Tables[0];

   for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
   {
      TreeNode firstchild = new TreeNode();
      firstchild.Text = " Shoes";
      firstchild.SelectAction = TreeNodeSelectAction.Select;
      TvCategories.Nodes.Add(firstchild);
      DataSet ds1 = new DataSet();
      ds1 = BindSubCategories(dt.Rows[i]["InventoryType"].ToString());
      DataTable dt1 = ds1.Tables[0];

      for (int j = 0; j < dt1.Rows.Count; j++)
      {
           TreeNode childnode = new TreeNode();
           childnode.SelectAction = TreeNodeSelectAction.Select;

           if (j == 0)
              childnode.Text = "Nike";
           if (j == 1)
              childnode.Text = "Rebok";
           if (j == 2)
              childnode.Text = "Addidas";
              firstchild.ChildNodes.Add(childnode);

       }
  }
```

Below is the image of treeview when I run the Web application in browser:
[image]

What I want to do?

By selecting the root node will also select all the child node and visa versa 
when I select any child or any root, an postback event will fire  and based on selecting I want to bind gridview.

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: Do you want to bind your grid according to the selection you have made?

Comment: yes I want to bind your grid according to the selection i have made.

Comment: my questions are: 

By selecting the root node how it will also select all the child node and visa versa ?
when I select any child or any root,how the postback event will fire ?

Comment: I updated answer.It cause `PostBack` on `CheckChanged`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you to append your child node value along with parent node value so when you're going to bind gridview based on user selection, it would be easy for you.

Check out below link that shows how to check parent-child node:

http://nilthakkar.blogspot.in/2009/04/check-uncheck-treeview-checkboxes-with_13.html

You can have valued of checked nodes of treeview with [Checkednodes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.treeview.checkednodes.aspx) property of treeview.

Check out following link that shows how to do it.

http://nilthakkar.blogspot.in/2009/05/retrieve-selected-treenode-value-at.html

Comment: thanx Nileshsir, This link (http://nilthakkar.blogspot.in/2009/04/check-uncheck-treeview-checkboxes-with_13.html) is helpful for me. Second link will not be used in my case. actually I want to bind grid based on check boxes selection. So I want to do postback the page based on the selection and not do postback with button click.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to post back on check changed:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
   e = e || window.event;
   var o = e.srcElement || e.target;
</script> 
    <asp:TreeView ID="TvCategories" runat="server" ShowCheckBoxes="All onclick="postBackByObject(this);" >
    </asp:TreeView>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById('<%=TvCategories.ClientID %>').addEventListener('click', postBackByObject);

</script>
```

some parts from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6731726/2040375)

Comment: still page is not postbacking. is this below event is right?    protected void TvCategories_TreeNodeCheckChanged(object sender, TreeNodeEventArgs e)
        {

        }

Comment: @CodeGuru my code cause post pack in opera and IE but not FF so if I have time will fix it then no extra action will needed and you can change checks on `PostBack` on `Page_Load`.

Comment: @mahidgeek microsoft says that treeview is not having autopostback property. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178259%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Comment: @CodeGuru yes,but with this code you can cause a manual `PostBack`

Comment: @mahidgeek ya that code i used but it is also not working..an I think it is not perfect solution. right??

Comment: @CodeGuru I'm asking another question to answer your question! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17295901/firefox-window-event-is-undefined-error