# Firefox "window.event is undefined" error

Tags: javascript, events, firefox

I have this script:

```
function postBackByObject(e) {
   var o = window.event.srcElement || e.target;
   if (o.tagName == "INPUT" && o.type == "checkbox") {
        __doPostBack("", "");
    }
}
```

I use this script with `onclick="postBackByObject();"`.

but in Firefox 21 I get this error:

> TypeError: window.event is undefined

what is my wrong?

Comment: Check this...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9813445/why-ff-says-that-window-event-is-undefined-call-function-with-added-event-list

Comment: @AyyappanSekar for URLs in comments use the format `[text](http://uri.com/)` [text](http://uri.com/)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

That's because it is. `window.event` is for older versions of IE.

The typical way to do this is:

```
function postBackByObject(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    var o = e.srcElement || e.target;
    // ...
}
```

Comment: the typical way is a **bitwise** OR?!

Comment: Sorry, typo, was supposed to be logical.

Comment: @Kolinik you're still missing a set of parenthesis so you don't get an invalid left-hand side in assignment exception `e||(e=x);`, or swap the `=` and `||` (but this is a re-assignment even if it's already assigned).

Comment: Ugh, this is what I get for not getting any sleep XD

Comment: What do you mean `e is undefined`? You just defined it in the function definition...

Comment: I know that,It is strange!

Comment: It gets slightly worse if you have an HTML tag on the page with an id="event", then THAT becomes window.event in FF (37)

Comment: This should be the correct answer because it explains WHY we are getting the "windows.event is undefined" error, while the Accepted answer doesn't. Much appreciated, Niet.

Answer (score 7):

You are attaching events inline `onclick="postBackByObject();"`

Try passing `this`(the event target) to `onclick="postBackByObject(this);"`
Modify your function to handle this change:

```
function postBackByObject(e) {
   if (e.tagName == "INPUT" && e.type == "checkbox") {
        __doPostBack("", "");
    }
}
```

A better alternative will be to attach events using `addEventListener`

If your markup looks like:

```
<div id="TvCategories" onclick="postBackByObject(this);" />
```

then

```
document.getElementById('TvCategories').addEventListener('click', postBackByObject);
```

Your `postBackByObject` function remains unchanged when using this approach.

Comment: excuse me;where I should put `obj.addEventListener('click', postBackByObject);`?

Comment: Which element has an `onclick='postBackByObject()'` present? BTW, the first approach should work: `onclick="postBackByObject(this);"`.

Comment: `<div id="TvCategories" onclick="postBackByObject();">`

Comment: The first approach mentions the use of `this` in the method call. `<div id="TvCategories" onclick="postBackByObject(this);">`

Comment: Please remove the first line from `postBackByObject`. argument e refers to the target object itself. I have updated my post with the new function.

Comment: Which is why I recommended using the 2nd approach. It will work for sure. When using the 2nd approach, keep your `postBackByObject` function as it is(do not remove the first statement).

Comment: For me, `onclick="postBackByObject(this)"` does not work, but `onclick="postBackByObject(event)"` does in FireFox.

Answer (score 3):

Pass the event on the `onClick` event like this:

`onclick="myCustomFunction(event);"`

It does work and you can access the event object!

Comment: This was very helpful. So the naming seems to be important, as using `this` instead of `event` will pass the object instead of the event

Answer (score 2):

It's possible to pass event object in the inline declaration:

```
<input type="button" onclick="postBackByObject(event);" value="click" />

function postBackByObject(e) {
    var o = e.srcElement || e.target;
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Attaching the event is a solution but there's an alternative one that could be helpful for other people facing the same problem, after a long search I found out that:

> Event object is only reconized by firefox if you send explicitly the 'event' from the function

So the problem occurs because `window.event` is not recognized by Firefox, and the solution is to pass `event` to the function, your code will be :

```
function postBackByObject(e) {
   var o = e.srcElement || e.target;
   if (o.tagName === "INPUT" && o.type === "checkbox") {
        __doPostBack("", "");
    }
}
```

And you can still call it in your inline HTML passing `event` as a parameter:

```
onclick="postBackByObject(event);"
```

Answer (score 1):

Your line

```
var o = window.event.srcElement || e.target;
```

fails on all browsers excepting IE, since for them `windows.event` is undefned

The proper formulation would be :

```
var o = e ? e.target : window.event.srcElement;
```

Since standard compliant browsers will pass the event as the parameter `e` and
the target at `e.target` in IE, `e` will be undefined and you must use 
`window.event.srcElement`

Note that recent versions of IE do support the standards compliant model.

On a more generic note, when you try and access a value as `a.b.c.d` then `a.b.c` must
be a defined object else you will get the error `a.b.c undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

i  am not sure if window.event  is supported in all browsers. I think you get event in variable  **"e"** of **postBackByObject(e)**