# Can't access to Event.repeat in firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

**This is not a duplicate of [Firefox "window.event is undefined" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17295901/firefox-window-event-is-undefined-error)**

I have this code:

```js
 $(window).on('keydown keyup', function(e){
       e.preventDefault();
       var repeat = window.event.repeat
       console.log(repeat); // Works in chrome
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Click here and hold down a key
```

In chrome it works (I get `true` if the key is hold down, false otherwise) , but in firefox I get this error : `TypeError: window.event is undefined` because window.event is not supported, but then I find that repeat **[is supported in firefox](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/repeat)**.

I try to use the variable `e` but it does not even work in chrome:

```js
 $(window).on('keydown keyup', function(e){
       e = e || window.event;
       var repeat = e.repeat
       console.log(repeat); // In this case repeat is always undefiend
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Click here and hold down a key
```

How can I access to Event.repeat property in Firefox?

Comment: It's not available in Firefox and is non-standard. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/event

Comment: @Walk, are you sure? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/repeat

Comment: I mean `window.event`, not `event.repeat`.